# Ubuntu Curl installation failed

Tags: ubuntu, curl, meteor, terminal

Hi I problem curl 60

I use code `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

How should I use terminal? How do I fix the problem?

[image: Screenshot_1_Meteor_Ubuntu]

Comment: Please post the output of `which curl` and try: `touch ~/.curlrc && echo "capath=\"/etc/ssl/certs/:\$capath\"" > ~/.curlrc`, maybe it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The text in your screenshot is barely visible, but it appears to be an SSL certificate problem.